# convex optimization with multiple nonsmooth terms

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, machine-learning, non-smooth-optimization

Is there a general algorithm for solving
$$ \min f(x) + g(x) + h(x) $$
where all three functions are convex and proximable, $f(x)$ is smooth, and $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are both nonsmooth?

Note that if the problem was just 
$$ \min f(x) + g(x) $$
then I could use proximal gradient descent.

Comment: [ADMM](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/admm.html) will work.

Comment: I can see how to use ADMM to optimize the sum of *two* proximable functions, but how do I extend that to handle the sum of three?

Comment: Minimize $\underbrace{f(x)}_{\text{first function}}+\underbrace{g(z_1)+h(z_2)}_{\text{second function}}$ subject to $\begin{bmatrix}x\\x\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: 2 smooth terms + 1 nonsmooth term $\equiv$ 1 smooth term + 1 nonsmooth term. So there is nothing to do here. Things become interesting when you have 1 smooth term and multiple nonsmooth terms...